# Why does the standard C++ library use all lower case?

Tags: c++, coding-style, lowercase, std

Just curious why the C++ standard library uses all lower case and underscores instead of `camelCase` or `PascalCase` naming convention.

Personally, I find the latter much easier to deal with when typing out code, but is there some kind of legitimate reason to use the former?

Comment: I'm assuming it's to keep the conventions the same as C.

Comment: Not *all* lower case.  Macros are `ALL_CAPS`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Main reason :** To keep compatibility with the existing code, since they have done it with C also.

Also have a look at these [C++ Coding standards](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/CppCodingStandard.html#noabbrev), which presents some generic reasoning regarding the importance of convention.

---

These links discusses about the naming conventions of C/C++ Standard Library.

- [Naming Convention for C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899555/what-naming-convention-for-a-c-api)
- [C/C++ Library Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734277/name-of-c-c-stdlib-naming-convention)
- [C Library Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988728/c-library-naming-conventions)
- [Why does Java use CamelCase, while C++ doesn't ?](http://www.quora.com/Why-does-Java-use-CamelCase-while-C-doesnt)

Comment: Useful link. Thanks! Here's another set of guidelines I've used in the past http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml

Comment: That's what I thought, and I do agree with the reasoning...but I think Microsoft would do well to agree as well XD

Comment: *"go through the C++ Coding standards"* - they're not *the* standards, they're one person's attempt to write up what they consider best practice, and at odds with many other peoples' equally-valid preferences.  The way you've phrased it implies the linked suggestions have more credibility than they do.  A quick google would turn up dozens of alternative standards - they best idea is to read over a few to flesh out some background knowledge of the pros and cons on any specific issue, then look at what practices the code base you're working in is already using - see whether it's worth changing.

Comment: I have rewritten the section talking about "the" coding standard. As it was, the message possibly implied was simply wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Convention.  They've done it that way all along, since the C days and before...and didn't see a good reason to break from that convention (not to mention potentially break compatibility with tons of existing code) just to add caps to a bunch of function names.