# camelCase vs snake_case in C/C++ identifiers and filenames

Tags: c++, c

snake_case seem to be the convention in most of the C sources I've come across.
camelCase is more comfy to type. Is there a good reason not use camelCase instead of snake_case?

I think a source of problems might be that identifiers tend to "leak" onto the filesystem (like when you name a file after an identifier), and some filesystem might not handle case-sensitive names well. But is that still a thing on platforms of 2015 worth porting to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414511/why-does-the-standard-c-library-use-all-lower-case

Comment: I have never seen anyone deliberately name a file after an identifier in a program outside "Introduction to programming" classes.

Answer (score 29):

There are papers about readability, e.g. [1].

> Although, no 
>   difference was found between identifier styles with respect to
>   accuracy, results indicate a significant improvement in time
>   and lower visual effort with the underscore style" [1]

[1] "An Eye Tracking Study on camelCase and
under_score Identifier Styles ", Bonita Sharif and Jonathan I. Maletic, http://www.cs.kent.edu/~jmaletic/papers/ICPC2010-CamelCaseUnderScoreClouds.pdf

Comment: Very interesting paper! I just love it when there's actual scientific studies about things like this, instead of subjective opinions by random programmers.